# how would i show a profile picture on my website from my database from the users?

Tags: php, html, mysql

this is the code i use for my user page atm it only shows their names out of the database

userlist.php

```
<?php
include "header.php";      
include "footer.php";
include "db_conn.php";

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="fotos/favicon.ico">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styletwo.css">
  <script src="java/currentime.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h3 style="text-align: center;">Users on the website</h3>
    <div id="usernamelist" style="border: solid black 1px; width: 60px; height: 20px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
    <?php if ($user) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users;";
 
    foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
        print $row['username'] . '<br>';   
    }

    /*
    $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if ($resultCheck > 0) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                echo $row['username'] . "<br>";
            }
        }*/

        }else { 
            header("Location: login.php");
            exit;
           } ?>
           </div>
           </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is what handles the pictures

profilepicture.php

```
 if (isset($_FILES['pp']['name']) AND !empty($_FILES['pp']['name'])) {
         
         
         $img_name = $_FILES['pp']['name'];
         $tmp_name = $_FILES['pp']['tmp_name'];
         $error = $_FILES['pp']['error'];
         
         if($error === 0){
            $img_ex = pathinfo($img_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $img_ex_to_lc = strtolower($img_ex);

            $allowed_exs = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png');
            if(in_array($img_ex_to_lc, $allowed_exs)){
               $new_img_name = uniqid($uname, true).'.'.$img_ex_to_lc;
               $img_upload_path = '../upload/'.$new_img_name;
               move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $img_upload_path);
```

this is what shows the profile pictures on the website when someone updated their profile or signed up now i wanna make it show it shows up on the website through the database  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRzhS.png)

Answer (score 1):

Since you saved user profile image in a folder, you should also insert its name in a column of user table (e.g profile_image) and by that, you can find each user's image.

```
# Inserting => After saving image in a folder
$query = "INSERT INTO $tableName (profile_image)
VALUES($new_img_name)";
$conn->query($query);
```

And then reading data.

```
function getUserData($id){
    # Reading
    global $conn;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE user_id=$id";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    $info = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    return $info;
}
```

And you can call this function like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <?php require('db_conn.php')?>
    <?php
    function getUserData($id){
        # Reading
        global $conn;
        $query = "SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE user_id=$id";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        $info = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        return $info;
    }

    ?>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$userInfo= getUserData($id); ?>
<img src='<?= "../upload/".$userInfo["profile_image"] ?>' alt="">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: oke thank you but how would i implement this in my code?

Comment: You should put `insert` part right after you saved the image in a folder. Then you can add `read` function in your `index.php` file and use this function in your HTML tags in `index.php`.

Comment: and how would i do this if i use PDO ?